# How can I bring my mother to UK for visit

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

Hi I’m British and my wife on spouse visa and we due a baby on November how can I bring my mother in law for visit ?

Comment: What's your, your wifes and and your mother in laws nationality?

Comment: @Hilmar Aman says in the question that they are British, but you are right that it would still be helpful to know everyone else's nationality.

Comment: @mlc Aman says he is British, but does not say so of his wife, and it must be assumed she is not, at least originally (otherwise there would be no need for the question). Would Aman's mother-in-law have any rights to enter, necessarily? We need to know their nationalities.

Comment: Title says *mother*; questions says *mother in law*

Answer (score 1):

Depends on nationality, you may have to apply for a standard visit visa for your mother in law.

Details: https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor/apply-standard-visitor-visa

You can apply online and show up for appointment, usually in VFS. After taking biometrics, it can take an average of 7 weeks at the moment. You can apply for a priority visa, if you need it earlier. You or your wife can be the sponsor and provide an invitation letter.

Your mother in law can stay upto six months for a visit.